# Lambda Help Grouping and Summing in C#, need a Func<IGrouping<int, anonymous type, int> or Expression<Func<IGrouping<int, anonymous type>, decimal>>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, lambda

I'm having a bit of trouble doing an inline .GroupBy() and .Sum() action.

I have a subset of data obtained via a let so it's return type is already anonymous. Hopefully there's enough code in this sample to show what I'm trying to achieve...

```
from r in Repo.R
  join f in Repo.F
    on f.ID equals r.FFK

let totalB = Repo.B
    .Join(
        b => b.FKID,
        f => f.ID
        (b, f) => new { b.ID, b.Qty, b.Fee })
    .Where(
        b => b.someCriteria == someInput)

group r by new 
   { 
      r.Name,
      TotalFee = totalB
                 .GroupBy(tb => tb.TypeId)
                 .Sum(  /*having trouble here*/ )
   }
into rgroup
select new FinalOutput
   {
        rgroup.Key.Name,
        rgroup.Key.TotalFee
   }
```

I need a valid:

```
Func<IGrouping<int, anonymous type>, int> selector
```

**or**

```
Expression<Func<IGrouping<int, anonymous type>, decimal>> selector
```

Comment: You forgot to mention what are you trying to do. You can use `g => g.Count()`, for one (just an example). Don't you have too many nested groups, by the way?

Comment: I believe I need the nested GroupBy to help split up a set of data, that's being fetched on a .Contains(List<int>) action, I need a few summing and count actions. I do need to sum a field that has a 'double' value and not just a count...

Comment: @SLaks, don't quite follow...

Comment: Could you give us an example set of data that you will be querying, and what you want out?

Answer (score 0):

See if you can write `.Sum(x => x.Key.Fee)`, but I doubt that the whole query will work or returns the expected result...

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the grouping into the Sum selector like this

```
.Sum(g => ...)
```

Here "g" is your grouping.  It has a key which is the value that it was grouped by, and it also contains all of the values that you grouped.  These are values of your anonymous type.

If you call Sum on "g" it'll give you the option of specifying a selector for your anonymous type.

```
//this is how you can sum values within a grouping
.Sum(g => g.Sum(tb => tb.Fee))
```

I've guessed "Fee" as the property name in my example, but once you de-reference the "tb" variable your intellisense should kick in and show you the properties available.

I hope this helps :-)